# Ng-src in a script tag

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a dynamic piece to my script tags url and I am getting "moudule unavailable" error

What I am ultimately looking for us something like this

`<script ng-src="js/angular/{{anotherfolder}}/filters.js"></script>`

I get the error even if I just do this

`<script ng-src="js/angular/filters.js"></script>` Basically it doesn't seem to like the `ng-src` directive

the non-dynamic way `<script src="js/angular/filters.js"></script>` works so I am reasonably sure that the problem is not the `filters.js` file

Comment: Are you sure angular is ready at the time you're loading that script?

Comment: No, how would I make sure? My ng-app is above all the script tags.

Answer (score -3):

Try including the whole path concatenation within the angular binding like this:

`<script ng-src="{{'js/angular/' + anotherfolder + '/filters.js'}}"></script>`